# How do I use the Facebook Buck building tool with Android Studio?

Tags: android, build, android-studio, buck

How do I use the Facebook Buck building tool with Android Studio?

The requirement is something like code in android studio but build through buck from command line.

Comment: just for records, it's Uber's not FB's building tool

Comment: @Ewoks it's FB's only - https://buckbuild.com/

The one you are referencing is okbuck.

Comment: my bad.. to clarify, OKBuck plugin (that simplify use buck build system with Android Studio and gradle) is from Uber..

Answer (score 4):

While we haven't explicietly tested this, Android Studio is essentially a customized IntelliJ.  You just need to setup the correct [*project_config*](http://facebook.github.io/buck/rule/project_config.html) rules, and then run [*buck project*](http://facebook.github.io/buck/command/project.html).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a gradle plugin [OkBuck](https://github.com/Piasy/OkBuck) which can let you start using BUCK base on your current Android Studio + Gradle build system with only **10** lines of configuration. Check it out.